# How can i log error from my script.sh every time I run the script.sh and save output to a file?

Tags: bash, bash4

How can I save the error output when running my script to a file?
I have my code bellow, but the code does not track error and save the error to test.log14.
Can somebody give me a hint on what could be wrong in my code...

```
 LOGFILE=/usr/local/etc/backups/test14.log

 "$(date "+%m%d%Y %T") : Starting work" >> $LOGFILE 2>&1
```

Comment: You seems to have missed "echo" before  "$(date "+%m%d%Y %T") : Starting work" >> $LOGFILE 2>&1

Comment: @VineethVenugopal Ok, I missed the echo, thanks. But the code is not saving error output to my file.

Answer (score 6):

There are normally 2 outputs that you see on your screen when you execute a command:

1. STDOUT
2. STDERR

You can redirect them independently per command.

For example:

```
ls >out 2>err
```

will give you two files; `out` will contain the output from `ls` and `err` will be empty.

```
ls /nonexisting 1>out 2>err
```

will give you an empty `out` file and `err` will contain

> "ls: cannot access /nonexisting: No such file or directory"

The `2>&1` redirects 2 (STDERR) to 1 (STDOUT)

Your `echo` does not have any errors, therefore there is no output on the STDERR.

So your code would probably need to be something like this:

```
echo "$(date "+%m%d%Y %T") : Starting work"
work_command > work_output 2>> $LOGFILE
```

Answer (score 5):

Use this code:

```
#!/bin/bash

LOGFILE=/usr/local/etc/backups/test14.log

(
    echo "$(date "+%m%d%Y %T") : Starting work"
    ... more commands ...
    echo error 1>&2 # test stderr

    echo "$(date "+%m%d%Y %T") : Done"
) >& $LOGFILE
```

The `()` makes BASH execute most of the script in a subshell. All output of the subshell (stderr and stdout) is redirected to the logfile.

Comment: Nice code, but the output in the logfile is not displaying the wrong command that i used, the error command.

Comment: @V.V.T: It works for me. My guess is that you're omitting some vital information. Edit your question: Show us more of the script, what output you get and what output you expect.

Answer (score 4):

Send the error output of the command instead of appending 'error output from append' -if that makes sense.  I typically use functions for this type of process (similar to above.)

Try this:

```
2>&1 >> $LOGFILE
```

instead of

```
>> $LOGFILE 2>&1

###
function run_my_stuff {
    echo "$(date "+%m%d%Y %T") : Starting work"
    ... more commands ...
    echo "$(date "+%m%d%Y %T") : Done"
}
## call function and append to log
run_my_stuff 2>&1 >> ${LOGFILE} # OR
run_my_stuff 2>&1 | tee -a ${LOGFILE} # watch the log
```